# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: TypeError: VoiceClient.play() missing 1 required positional argument: 'source'

Tags: python, discord.py, youtube-dl, ffmpeg-python

I'm using python to work on a discord bot that plays music. I'm using YoutubeDL and FFmpeg

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from functools import wraps
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

#Voice Client
voice_client = discord.VoiceClient

#YoutubeDL Options
ytdl_opts = {
    'format':'best audio/best',
    'noplaylist':'True'
}

ytdl = YoutubeDL(ytdl_opts)

class test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    def search_yt(self, song):
        song_info = ytdl.extract_info('ytsearch:%s'%song, download = False)['entries'][0]
        return {'source': song_info['formats'][0]['url'], 'title': song_info['title']}

    #Music Play Function
    @commands.command()
    async def play_music(self, ctx, *args):
        '''Play music of your choice. Type in url or name'''
        song = ' '.join(args)
        source = self.search_yt(song)
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        print(isinstance(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source['source']), discord.AudioSource))
        await voice_channel.connect()
        await ctx.send(source['source'])
        voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source['source']), after=None)

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(test(bot))
```

With the command !play (song name), the bot searches (song name) on youtube and picks the first item and extracts the url. But the error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "B:\Programming Stuff\Python\Python Programme Files\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 229, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "b:\Programming Stuff\Python\Coding_Files\Discord Bot\Cogs\test.py", line 37, in play
    voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source['source']), after=None)
TypeError: VoiceClient.play() missing 1 required positional argument: 'source'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "B:\Programming Stuff\Python\Python Programme Files\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1349, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "B:\Programming Stuff\Python\Python Programme Files\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1023, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\Programming Stuff\Python\Python Programme Files\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 238, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: VoiceClient.play() missing 1 required positional argument: 'source'
```

The error tells me that TypeError: VoiceClient.play() missing 1 required positional argument: 'source'. However, I checked whether `discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source['source'])` is an AudioSource using `print(isinstance(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source['source']), discord.AudioSource))`. The output is `True`. But the error states that it's missing an AudioSource.

I have also tried to play the mp3 file directly using

```
    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx):
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        await voice_channel.connect()
        print(isinstance(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('song.mp3'), discord.AudioSource))
        voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('song.mp3'))
```

but I still get the same error.

I have downloaded the full build of FFmpeg. I have added the path to FFmpeg.exe both the user variables and system variables for the environment variables. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Is there a way to do this without having to download the audio? (i.e set download=True in `song_info = ytdl.extract_info('ytsearch:%s'%song, download = False)['entries'][0]`) Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `voice_client` variable is not an instance of the `VoiceClient class`:

```py
#Voice Client
voice_client = discord.VoiceClient
```

it's just the name of the class. You have to actually create an *instance* of it.

However, you should never have to do this manually. The library will create one for you when connecting to a channel, and then you can just access that one.

Refer to the official Voice example: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py

> Is there a way to do this without having to download the audio?

The official example above also does this already at [line 47](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py#L47).

> But the error states that it's missing an AudioSource.

The error is telling you that the argument is missing, because the first argument of a method is always `self`. This is passed automatically if you create an instance. However, as you did not, this is never passed, so your `source` argument is treated as `self` and the value for the actual argument (`source`) is missing.